# How to update MS Word preview of a Worksheet object after changing the values inside it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I paste special as "Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object" in Microsoft Word the table would appear like this (Normal Sheet):

[image: Normal Sheet]

When I double click it to edit, it appears like this and I can change values (Edit Sheet):

[image: Edit Sheet]

When I click anywhere in the file to exit the sheet editing, my values don't get updated and the sheet looks like this now (Corrupted preview):

[image: Corrupted preview]

When I double click it again and enter editing mode then exit, the values would update but the preview still shows the sheet's scroll bar, columns and rows (Wrong preview):

[image: Wrong preview]

Please note I tried to do this on multiple PCs one of them had Office 2019 and the 2 others had Office 365, and I got the same behavior.

And the preview gets updated and appears correctly momentarily while I change the zoom value of the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+"Wheel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a new update bug and reverting back solved the problem.

```
<Configuration>
<Updates Enabled="TRUE" TargetVersion="16.0.14827.20198" />
</Configuration>
```